# Proofs regarding range and kernel of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $V$ is a finite dimensional space and $S, T\in L(V)$, prove the
>   following statements:
>
> $(i)$ $\dim Im(S+T)\le\dim Im(S)+\dim Im(T)$.
>
> ***Hint***: each element in $Im(S+T)$ is a linear combination of some
>   elements in $Im (S)\cup Im(T)$
>
> $(ii)$ $\dim Im(I−ST)\le \dim Im(I−S)+\dim Im(I−T)$
>
> $(iii)$ $T=P_1\ldots P_k$ with $P_i\in L(V)$ satisfying
>   $P_{2i}=P_i, i\in\{1,\ldots, k\}.$  Prove that $\dim Im(I−T)\le k\dim
>  \operatorname{null}(T)$.
>
> Where $Im$ denotes the range.

$(i)$ I try to solve it by using nullity: $\dim(\operatorname{null}(ST))\le\dim(\operatorname{null}(S))+\dim(\operatorname{null}(T))$ and it worked. So, does it work for $\dim Im(ST)\le\dim Im(S)+\dim Im(T)$?

$(ii)$ I have no idea how to prove.

Comment: How are Pi and T related? Also, what is k?

Comment: i=1,2,.....k because I cannot write the full exercise

Comment: You don't have to write the full exercise in the title. You have plenty of room in the body of the question. Also, it's very difficult to read your problems. Please use MathJax to format your questions, so we can read them.

Comment: IfVis  a  finite  dimensional  space  andS, T∈ L(V).   Prove  the  followingstatements:(i)  dim range(S+T)≤dim rangeS+ dim rangeT.(Hint:  each element in range(S+T) is a linear combination of some elements inrangeS∪rangeT)(ii)  dim range(I−ST)≤dim range(I−S) + dim range(I−T).(iii)T=P1···PkwithPi∈ L(V)  satisfiesP2i=Piwherei=  1,···, k.   Prove  thatdim range(I−T)≤kdim nullT. here is full of exercise. i) is proved

Comment: Oh, so $T$ is the product (i.e. composition) of linear operators $P_1 \ldots P_k$, such that $P_i^2 = P_i$ for all $i$?

Comment: yeah, you are right. how can we figure it out?

Comment: I edited your post, please, tell me if you used a different notation and correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the range of $ST$ is contained in the range of $S$ we get $dim (Ran \,  (ST)) \leq dim(Ran \, S) \leq dim(Ran \, S)+dim(Ran \,T)$/

In ii) the range of $I-\pi$ is a subset of the null space of $\pi$ so $dim (Ran \, (I-\pi)) \leq dim (Null \, \pi)$.